# How to handle the runtime overflow in exp of a geometric regression model objective function?

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement a Scikit-learn compatible class for a geometric distribution regression model. However, I am getting an overflow runtime error in my objective function which has an `exp` component. I am also having a similar error in my objective_grad function which finds the gradient at every step.

The code for my objective function which calculates the objective value using the parameters is given below:

```py
        weight = wb[0:-1]
        bias = wb[-1]
        theta = X.dot(weight) + bias
        obj = y.dot(theta)
        obj += np.sum((y + 1).dot((np.log(1 + np.exp(-theta)))))
        obj += self.lam * np.sum(np.square(weight))
        return obj
```

I am trying to use log sum trick to solve this issue but I am not sure how to apply in this component: `np.log(1+np.exp(-theta))`

I have also shared the code for my gradient function which is also having similar issue for overflow:

```py
        weight = wb[:-1]
        bias = wb[-1]

        theta = X.dot(weight) + bias
        common_grad = y / (1 + np.exp(-theta)) - 1 / (1 + 
                                                  np.exp(theta))
        dw = X.T.dot(common_grad) - 2 * self.lam * weight
        db = -np.sum(common_grad) - 2 * self.lam * bias
        dwb = np.hstack((dw, db))
        return dwb
```

What should be my approach to handle the exp problem in this scenario?

Comment: For the purpose of troubleshooting I would test with a try/except block around the expression, with "print(-theta)" in the except.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. In this line,

`obj += np.sum((y + 1).dot((np.log(1 + np.exp(-theta)))))`,

`np.log(1 + np.exp(-theta)` was exploding.

I resolved it by using

`-np.log(1/(1 + np.exp(theta))`